# How to write text into a table cell within a document?

Tags: text, google-apps-script, cell, document

I can't figure out how to write text into a table cell within a document.  I can read the cell, `getRow(0).getCell(0)`, but I can't change the text within the cell.

As noted in the comments below, my variable text does show the old cell string has been cleared and the new string inserted; however, the actual cell in my document remains unchanged, containing the original, old string.

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();    
var tables = doc.getTables();    
var cell = tables[0].getRow(0).getCell(0);    
var text = cell.getText();      // the string is the expected from document.    
cell.clear();    
cell.setText('text');    
var text = cell.getText();     // text = 'text' but the cell on document remains unchanged.
```

Comment: You should indicate the language and the technology you are using. It will help other to give you an answer. What is it? Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.editAsText()` to get the [`Text` object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text) inside of the cell.

```
var text = cell.editAsText();
```

A strong from the `Text` object can be retrieved with:

```
var string = text.getText();
```

And set with:

```
text.setText('blahblah');
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help-generosity.  I'm new to the JS sport and I'm enjoying it.  I was dancing all around the answer without realizing it.